# Android List with onclicklistener using SampleAdapter

Tags: android

How to let users click on the selected item in the list menu and after select it will intent to another page. I know this question have been asked a lot in stackoverflow but i have gone through most of it and i am still lose. Hope i can have some help here.

**Example:** When the user select "a" in the list it will go to another activity how do i implement `onclick listener` in this code?

After editing, my intent doesn't work in another way.
I added the code on my main but when i run the program i still can't click

```
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            // write your start another activity code here
            switch(i){
            case 0:{
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(LeftAndRightActivity.this, DisplayActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
            }
        }
    });
```

**rightlistfragment.xml**

```
public class RightListFragment extends ListFragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.rightlist, null);

}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    SampleAdapter adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity());
    adapter.add(new SampleItem("a"));
    adapter.add(new SampleItem("b"));
    adapter.add(new SampleItem("c"));
    adapter.add(new SampleItem("d"));
    adapter.add(new SampleItem("e"));
    adapter.add(new SampleItem("f"));
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            // write your start another activity code here
            switch(i){
            case 0:{
                startActivity(new Intent(RightListFragment.this,FragmentBindAcc.class));
            }
            }
        }       

    TextView text1 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.loginName);

    text1.setText("TEST");
}

private class SampleItem {
    public String tag;
    public int iconRes;
    public SampleItem(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag; 

    }
}

public class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SampleItem> {

    public SampleAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rightrow, null);
        }
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrow);
        icon.setImageResource(getItem(position).iconRes);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
        title.setText(getItem(position).tag);


        return convertView;
    }

}
   }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this by the `setOnItemClickListener` of the `ListView` as follows:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(arg2){
            case 0:{  

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityA.class));                     
                }
            break;  
            case 1:{

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityB.class));
                                    }   
            break;
            case 2:{  
                ExampleQuestion.topicNo=3;                          
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityC.class));                     
            }
            break;              
}
```

You can think of it as the `listview` contains A, B and C. When user selects A, it is the Case 0 and for B Case 2 and for C case 3.

Comment: The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){} what does this means?

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(RightListFragment.this,FragmentBindAcc.class)); i changed it to .this also doesn't work

Comment: Instead of getApplicationContext() method you can write your activity name as follows:   startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this,ActivityB.class));

Comment: tried that and i have an error . error message is on top thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        SampleAdapter adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity());
        adapter.add(new SampleItem("a"));
        adapter.add(new SampleItem("b"));
        adapter.add(new SampleItem("c"));
        adapter.add(new SampleItem("d"));
        adapter.add(new SampleItem("e"));
        adapter.add(new SampleItem("f"));
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                // write your start another activity code here
            }
        });
        TextView text1 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.loginName);

        text1.setText("TEST");
}
```

Comment: Hello , //write your start another activity code here. 
What kind of code should I write if user select a? Example in my if statement wad i need to write, if(//wad to write to compare with "a") is it if(i ==0), elseif(i==1)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to give onClickListner in your getView method

```
  title.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(context,anotherActivity.class);
                                      context.startActivity(i);

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        /* your code */
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RightListFragment rightListFragment = new RightListFragment();
rightListFragment.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int index, long l)         
            {
                swtich(index)
                {
                   // your implementaion
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

listview .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()

{

```
    @Override

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        if(arg2==0){  

                startActivity(new Intent(yourclass.this,ActivityA.class));                     
            }

     if(arg2=1){

                startActivity(new Intent(yourclass.this,ActivityB.class));}
  if(arg2==2)
      {  

            startActivity(new Intent(yourclass.this,ActivityC.class));                     
        }


        }`
```