# Can't run application when i change the ID of ListView

Tags: android

It's weird I have 2 list view in my program. First list view i set  android:id="@android:id/list"
and the 2nd listview my id I set android:id="@+id/list1".

Is this the correct method? As I can't run if I set my 2nd listview id to android:id="@+id/list1" so I was wondering is it because it's the id fault or there's a problem in my code.

I am using jeremy library with actionbarsherlock. I merely follow jeremy example which i don't find him using any listView findviewbyid(list) to get his menu. And after i change the id my application just crashed.
Thanks

rightlist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/listright"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding" />
```

leftlist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listleft"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding" />
```

LeftListFragment.java

```
public class LeftListFragment extends ListFragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.leftlist, null);
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    SampleAdapter adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity());
    adapter.add(new SampleItem("a"));
    adapter.add(new SampleItem("b"));
    adapter.add(new SampleItem("c"));
    adapter.add(new SampleItem("d"));
    adapter.add(new SampleItem("e"));
    setListAdapter(adapter);


}

private class SampleItem {
    public String tag;

    public SampleItem(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag; 

    }
}

public class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SampleItem> {

    public SampleAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.leftrow, null);
        }

        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_title1);
        title.setText(getItem(position).tag);

        return convertView;
    }

}
    }
```

rightlistfragment.java

```
 public class RightListFragment extends ListFragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.rightlist, null);
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    SampleAdapter adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity());
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        adapter.add(new SampleItem("Sample List", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search));
    }
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private class SampleItem {
    public String tag;
    public int iconRes;
    public SampleItem(String tag, int iconRes) {
        this.tag = tag; 
        this.iconRes = iconRes;
    }
}

public class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SampleItem> {

    public SampleAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rightrow, null);
        }
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_icon);
        icon.setImageResource(getItem(position).iconRes);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
        title.setText(getItem(position).tag);

        return convertView;
    }

}
 }
```

Main activity/leftandrightactivity.java

```
public class LeftAndRightActivity extends BaseActivity {

public LeftAndRightActivity() {
    super(R.string.left_and_right);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new LeftListFragment())
    .commit();

    getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_frame_two);
    getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.menu_frame_two, new RightListFragment())
    .commit();
}

   }
```

error log

```
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.peopeo.peopeo1/com.peopeo.peopeo1.LeftAndRightActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:344)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at     android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:145)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:941)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:556)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1167)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5216)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2073)
10-29 17:06:52.085: E/AndroidRuntime(26618):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Done , i couldn't run it when i change the id . But without changing there's no problem

Comment: Did you just change the id in XML file? If so then your ListView variable (list) isn't linked to the right resource. You need to change its initialization to: `list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1)` (or whatever your new ID is

Comment: I did but the problem is when i change to list1 it doesn't run

Comment: What error do you get, please post the LogCat

Comment: There's nothing on my LogCat but when i run on my phone it say unfortunately, appname has stopped. But when i change the 2 listview ID to list i can run the app smoothly whereas i can't have 2 same id because i have to put an onclicklistener in my program.

Comment: It's impossible that LogCat doesn't show anything when the app crashes. Check that your LogCat is monitoring all the processes and run the app till it crashes again.

Comment: sorry i have to restart ecilpse for my error log to work

Comment: Don't really understand Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: That means you're loading the wrong XML in the `setContentView()` method. Or rather that the XML file you've loaded doesn't have the element with mentioned id (`android:id/list`)

Comment: Okay let me post a full coding here simplfied verision that doesn't work hope you could help me, have been stuck for days without progressing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ListFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) expects the layout to contain a `ListView` with id `@android:id/list`:

> ListFragment has a default layout that consists of a single list view. However, if you desire, you can customize the fragment layout by returning your own view hierarchy from `onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)`. To do this, your view hierarchy *must* contain a ListView object with the id `"@android:id/list"` (or `list` if it's in code)

It's perfectly fine to have the same id in more than one place.

So just set the `ListView` id to `@android:id/list` in both layouts.

Comment: So if i do that, If i want a on click listener on the left and right menu which do different things how it differentiate left list and right list?

Comment: @LeowZhengXu Set the click listeners in `onCreateView()` of the corresponding fragment.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but i am kind of new to programming so i appreciate if you give me more explaination on it :( i don't really get what you mean. But i have tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651757/android-list-with-onclicklistener-using-sampleadapter on my code with list but it doesn't work

Comment: Use a simple fragment not a list fragment then you can set any name as id for the listviews

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @NitroNbg, you should specify your new ID. like **android:id="@+id/listId"**

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listId);
```

or check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) one.

Answer (score 0):

Your BaseActivity is extended from a ListActivity ? Your exception is indicating that...

Comment: public class BaseActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity